# find value in dictionary using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I need to find value in dictionary using regex in Python. When value containing that regex doesn't exist, loop must return False. But in my code, it only checks one element of dictionary.

```
 for value in dictionary.values():
     if re.search(myregex, str(value)):
         print value
         break
     else:
         print("no value found")
         return false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to dedent the `else` part so it only gets executed if the `for` loop doesn't `break` out:

```
for value in dictionary.values():
    if re.search(myregex, str(value)):
        print value
        break
else:
    print("no value found")
    return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a next with a return value if not found (stop iteration):

```
v = next((value for value in dictionary.values() if re.search(myregex, str(value))), False)
print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the else part.

**Ex:**

```
def checkVal(dictionary):
    for value in dictionary.values():
         if re.search(myregex, str(value)):
             return value
    return False
```